# Unable to mock SendGrid with Jest

Tags: node.js, node-modules, sendgrid, ts-jest

I'm looking for the ability to turn on or off mocking of the **SendGrid** client in my Jest tests; sometimes I want to mock it, but other times I don't.

I have various APIs which send emails with SendGrid but I don't always need to unit test the actual emailing so I'd like to mock the library. However, if I try to mock the library within a `.test.ts` file it never gets mocked.

For example:

```ts
// myapi.test.ts
import sgMail, { ClientResponse } from '@sendgrid/mail';

// this syntax doesn't work (though other libs were mocked similarly in this project)
jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail');
const mockedMail = sgMail as jest.Mocked<typeof sgMail>;
mockedMail.setApiKey.mockImplementation(jest.fn());
mockedMail.send.mockImplementation(jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{} as ClientResponse, {}])));

// this syntax doesn't work either
const mockedMail = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof sgMail>('@sendgrid/mail');
mockedMail.setApiKey = jest.fn();
mockedMail.send = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{} as ClientResponse, {}]));

// this is the most common syntax advocated, but doesn't work either
jest.mock('@sendgrid/mail', () => ({
  setApiKey: jest.fn(),
  send: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{} as ClientResponse, {}])),
}));

describe('some test suite', () => {
 // when tests are executed SendGrid is not mocked
});
```

The only way I could force Jest to mock the library was to create a `src/__mocks__/@sendgrid/mail.ts` file but this is a draconian solution -- I cannot write any tests that *don't* mock the library, or that use SendGrid's sandbox mode.

```ts
// src/__mocks__/@sendgrid/mail.ts
import sgMail, { ClientResponse } from '@sendgrid/mail';

const mockedMail = jest.createMockFromModule<typeof sgMail>('@sendgrid/mail');

mockedMail.setApiKey = jest.fn();
mockedMail.send = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve([{} as ClientResponse, {}]));

export default mockedMail;
```

With this I can unit test any of the application's code and the SendGrid functionality will be mocked, but I can't turn it *off* if I want to write a test in which it isn't mocked (e.g. to use sandbox mode).

So I'm wondering if there is a syntax that will work for defining the mocks within a `.test.ts` file?